# request before another request axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

How can i simplify this code? I need to make a request to get the token, before requesting the server to get the data. Then write this token to localstorage so as not to re-call a request for a token.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = localStorage.getItem("token");
  axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/json/em/pos/poses`, {
    limit,
    offset,
    contractType: 0,
    ...filter,
  })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(reducerGetOutlets({data: res.data, limit, offset: 0}));
    });
} else {
  axios(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/user/info`)
    .then((response) => {
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Basic " + response.data.token;
      localStorage.setItem("token", "Basic " + response.data.token);
      axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/json/em/pos/poses`, {
        limit,
        offset,
        contractType: 0,
        ...filter,
      })
        .then((res) => {
          dispatch(reducerGetOutlets({data: res.data, limit, offset: 0}));
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a couple things to simplify this code:

1. Use `async/await` syntax for your API calls instead of callbacks
2. Split your code into smaller functions.

For example:

```
async function getToken() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  } else {
    const response = await axios(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/api/user/info`);
    const token = "Basic " + response.data.token;
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    return token;
  }
}

async function fetchData() {
  const token = await getToken();
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;
  const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/json/em/pos/poses`, {
    limit,
    offset,
    contractType: 0,
    ...filter,
  });
  dispatch(reducerGetOutlets({ data: response.data, limit, offset: 0 }));
}

fetchData();
```

Here you get two functions: `getToken()` and `fetchData()`.

`getToken()` function checks if the token is in the `localStorage` and if not it makes a request to get the token and writes it to `localStorage`.

`fetchData()` function awaits the token from `getToken()`, sets the `Authorization` header and makes the request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: good example, i thought about axios.interceptors but your example also very good